# Replace content of a plist iphone

Tags: iphone, string, plist

I have a plist made of string, what I'd like to do is to replace the content if this plist by the content of an another array, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Please read [Property List Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html)!

Comment: Just write the new plist to location of the old one.